# Init YouTube iframe player without video ID

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to init YouTube iframe player without actualy loading video itself?
If do not provide *videoId* video is not loaded (no errors is shown) and player instance remains in "ready" state.

```
ytPlayer = new YT.Player('video-player', {
        height:   '100%',
        width:    '100%',
        videoId:  'video-id-goes-here',
        playerVars: {
                    .....
                    .....
```

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, if you want to, the following code does work:

```
<script>
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var player = new YT.Player('player', { 
      events: {
        onReady: function() {
          player.loadVideoById('sOEAD-gfJ_M');
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="//www.youtube.com/player_api" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Alternatively, if you know you're going to be loading a playlist, you can leave out `videoId` and put in

```
playerVars: {
  list: 'PLAYLIST_ID'
}
```

But while both of those approaches do work, what are you trying to accomplish? There might be a better way of doing it than initializing a YT.Player without the `videoId`.

Comment: It seems that leaving the `videoID` parameter blank is no longer valid, since 2013 according to one source.